# Why are the Wygwam toolbar icons not showing?

Tags: wygwam

I am running Expression Engine 2.6.1 and Wygwam 3.0.2 but the icons do not show up in the field. I could use some help getting them to show up properly.

I get the following error when the page loads in Chrome:

```
chrome.tabs is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. [VM] binding (1054):216
Binding.generate [VM] binding (1054):216
(anonymous function) [VM] tabs (1140):43
(anonymous function) measureIt.js:120
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined measureIt.js:120
GET http://independence4seniors.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins/wygwam3/skin.js?t=D09H5XK 404 (Not Found) ckeditor.js:16
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

I reloaded the theme but still get the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-download WYGWAM and try it again. There's a missing or corrupt file in there.

If you use Channel Images, make sure you add the WYGWAM plugin to the Channel Images themes directory or you'll get a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

For me this normally happens if I forget to upload the themes directory.

When you upgraded did you reinstall the Wygwam themes into your /themes/third-party directory?

Comment: Yes, I did and double did it to make sure.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but Im getting this problem using Channel Images 5.4.18 and Wygwam 3.3.21 on a localhost install, using Blocks to bring in the Wygwam field. The icon shows in the Wygwam config, I drag it to the tool bar but it doesn't show up in the publishing field. Ive double checked I have third_party folders installed for both add ons, what am i doing wrong? (Im using a clean install of EE 2.9.2.)